# Java jTable displaying question marks instead of utf-8 characters

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, netbeans-8

I'm facing this issue with a java application program. I'm binding a jtable in my gui to mysql database and using the jtable to display the records in the database. 
I have to insert Arabic characters in some field, however the jtable displays question marks instead of these characters after inserting the data from the java program. Both my program and mysql are using utf-8 encoding. 
The characters are displayed when inserting the records directly using phpmyadmin.
I've changed region and language on my windows 7 so it would fit the arabic language but still have the problem.
My GUI contains labels with Arabic words so i think the problem here is with the jtable.

Comment: Change the font with one that supports the charset you are using

Comment: I've tried this also and didn't work

Comment: What did you try?  Are there custom renderers involved?

Comment: Unicode and computers have a love-hate relationship. The easiest way is to give up.

Comment: @MadProgrammer no I'm using the default render. just to mention the jtable displays the characters just find when the records are entered directly in MySQL and displays the question marks after entering the records from the java GUI

Comment: How are you loading the values from the database? Have you verified that the text has been loaded properly?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't get your question clearly but the values are displayed in the jtable which is bounded to the database. I'm inserting the values from text fields using the 
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (?,?,?) //For examlple// using the prepared statement.
as i mentioned above i've inserted data with arabic characters directly into my database and faced no problem both on the web page (phpmyadmin) and the jtable in my program when displaying those data. the problem is only with displaying the inserted data on the jtable in java prog

Comment: Okay, but what does the text look like when you've loaded it from the database?  Is it coming from the database correctly?

Comment: no the data inserted from java prog appears as question marks both in the jtable and in the database
by the way my database is UTF-8 too